# How to access HDMI in port? Yes, my system has two HDMI ports one for output and the other for input

Tags: 14.10, hdmi

I am able to access my HDMI inport in Windows to see my Raspberry pi display.
Is there any way to do the same in Ubuntu.
Main goal is to project a windows system using its hdmi out port to my laptops hdmi in port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Linux, you need [VDPAU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU) to enable that feature.

For 14.10, the easiest way to install that is to:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-utopic
```

For 14.04, it's:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-vdpau-drivers-lts-trusty
```

What you've got now is a display port that needs [additional software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDPAU#Software_that_supports_VDPAU) to actually display the "video" content that is being "projected" onto the HDMI IN and you've probably already got that: VLC player.  If not:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Then, in VLC, you need to go to Tools → Preferences → Input / Codecs → Hardware-accelerated decoding to enable `vdpau`.